# Fix Page Height to slide up with footer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, facebook

I need some help with a Facebook webpage I'm making. I have a couple sliding divs that slide up and down when specific buttons are clicked.

The trouble I'm having is that the height of the webpage slides down with the toggled divs, but when the divs are toggled to slide back up I'm left with a empty block of webpage at the bottom below my footer. Can anyone help me out?

https://www.facebook.com/TheBackyrdCricketr?sk=app_203351739677351&ref=s

If you click the "about" button twice then scroll to the bottom of the page you will see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Define the minimum width of the sliding div. From minimum width it will occupy the specified area and will not scroll and even footer will be stay at bottom.

```
Check JsFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/6w46v/1/
```

You can keep footer at bottom of screen, by defining in CSS :

```
  #footer{ bottom : 0px; position: absolute}
```

Comment: Sorry I don't see how this will work as the div is hidden, then when the button is clicked it slides out/down from its hidden position creating "extra space/webpage". When the button is clicked agian the div slides up/is hidden, the rest of the divs below including the footer all slide up, but the the extra "space/webpage" doesn't slide up it's still left at the bottom of the webpage below the footer.

Comment: If content is same in all sliding div's then define height of parent div.